# How to match a Firestore rule on the database name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have rules in my database to restrict users to only access data that belongs to their own account id. For debugging purposes, I would like to give all users of our own company access to all other user data.

Something like this works:

```
 match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function matchesUserAccountId(accountId) {
      return request.auth.token.account_id == accountId ||
      request.auth.token.account_id == "our_own_account_id"
    }

    match /some_collection/{accountId}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if matchesUserAccountId(accountId)
    }
}
```

But this would obviously be a bad idea for a production database. So I would like to limit this to only our development database.

However, the following doesn't seem to work:

```
 match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function matchesUserAccountId(accountId) {
      return request.auth.token.account_id == accountId ||
      (database == "our_dev_project_id" && request.auth.token.account_id == "our_own_account_id")
    }

    match /some_collection/{accountId}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if matchesUserAccountId(accountId)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the `database` variable wouldn't match with the project id. I can't seem to find any info on what it might be instead. I initialize Firebase with:

```
databaseURL: `https://${process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com`,
```

So FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID is what I'm trying to match with. Should I use something else maybe?

Comment: Can you please explain "limit this to only our development database." (are you referring to another project)? You can only have 1 Firestore database instance per project so that `{database}` wildcard has value `(default)`. Also the `databaseURL` is related to realtime database.

Comment: Yes, we have a separate project for production and dev/staging. Since firebase.json can only refer to a single rules file, I can not easily specify different rules for each project, so I'd like to make the distinction as part of the rule database variable.

Comment: In that case `{database}` will be `(default)` for both projects as mentioned earlier. One way would be add a document `configs/project` and store project ID as field. Then you can use `get()` in security rules to read project ID. You'll have to make sure that no one else can update that field.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's good to know. I think for now I will just resort to deploying the debug database rules manually when I need to open up document access. On second thought it doesn't seem very wise to have different security rules between dev and production, and I only need it on specific occasions.

Maybe you could post something similar to your last message as an answer so I can accept it and close the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Firebase project can have only 1 Firestore instance at the moment and the value of `{database}` wildcard is `(default)`. You cannot get the project ID in security rules but a workaround would be to store the project ID in a document that no one else can update and read that in the rules using [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) function.

[Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) might be useful as well. You can set a claim "role" that'll be set in dev project *only*. So the following rule will pass in that project only:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId || hasAdminRoleClaim();
```

But you'll have to ensure no one can create a user with that role in production project.